# Run-time error 3075

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got this error message "Syntax error in query expression 'Select sum([BatteryDataTable].NumberOfBatter as)'"

Original sql statement below:

```
sqlDateRangeSearch = "Select *, **Select sum([BatteryDataTable].NumberOfBattery as " & Me.SumOfBattery & ")** from BattryDataTable" & _
" where BatteryDateChanged BETWEEN " & _
Format(Me.FromDTPicker.Value, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & " and " & _
Format(Me.ToDTPicker.Value, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & ";"
Me.RecordSource = sqlDateRangeSearch
```

What I am trying to do is to display all selected records, sum of values of all selected records, between selected dates. A selected records will display in a form, and the sum of values of all selected records, is displayed in textbox in the same form. BTW, somebody on here has helped me with this code. I was deeply appreciated. The part of the syntax in bold has caused the error. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a write an SQL, you are not required to repeat statements such as `SELECT`, `WHERE` etc. You simply separate your selected staements with a `comma` as you have done already. Removing the second instance that you have mentioned `SELECT` will hopefully remove the error for you.

Answer (score 0):

Many issues with your SQL.

- as Dane wrote, you don't need to repeat a `SELECT` in this SQL
  statement
- the alias name you give for your sum column have to be included in
  your SQL (within the double quotes) & should be outside of the closing bracket of the `SUM`
- the `**` you use before & after the `SUM` are irrelevant.

So here is your modified SQL Statement.

```
sqlDateRangeSearch = "Select *, sum(NumberOfBattery) as SumOfBattery from BattryDataTable" & _
" WHERE BatteryDateChanged BETWEEN " & _
Format(Me.FromDTPicker.Value, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & " AND " & _
Format(Me.ToDTPicker.Value, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & ";"
Me.RecordSource = sqlDateRangeSearch
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much both for your help. I have tried your both suggestions, but not working. I have come up with this. Please see below. Got error message as Run-time Error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression GROUP BY ID'. Usually, It may relate to incorrect spelling some where in statement. I have checked many time for spelling all the names, they should be all correct. I must have missed something else. Please advise. Thank you very much in advance. Please see the code on next tag.

Comment: sqlDateRangeSearch = "SELECT *, SUM(BatteryNumber) as '" & Me.SumOfBattery & "' from BatteryDataTable" & _
    " WHERE BatteryDateChanged BETWEEN " & _
    Format(Me.FromDTPicker.Value, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & " AND " & _
    Format(Me.ToDTPicker.Value, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & " ORDER BY ASCENDING, GROUP BY ID, Wings, RoomUnit, RoomNumber, Devices, BatteryDateChanged;"